# How is T-subject agreement realized on a verb in minimalist syntax?

Tags: syntax, agreement, minimalism

Consider the derivation of *John eats the apples.*

(1)  [CP C [TP John T [v*P **John** v*-eats [VP **eat** [DP the apples]]]]] 
                   [uφ]       [φ]                 [uφ]           [φ]

The bracket notation above, where the words in boldface type indicate copy/trace.

The phi-feature of *the apples* and uphi-feature of *eat* agree. This agreement is not morphologically realized in English.
The phi-feature of *John* and uphi-feature of T agree.  This agreement is realized on the verb *eat* by -s morpheme.  But how?  the verb is never in agree relation with *John.*

Untill Chomsky (1995), Minimalist Program,

Comment: Funny, it doesn't ***look*** minimal.

Comment: Adger 2003, 6.3.3. Subject-verb agreement, pp. 220-222. BTW what makes you say that "the verb is never in Agree relation with John?"

Comment: There seems to be no stage in which the verb enters Agree relation with the subject, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism of Agree(ment) has been redefined since Chomsky 1995. Since Chomsky 2000, 2001, it does not rely on Spec-Head agreement anymore. Regarding the relation between the subject and V, if suggest to have a look at [Pesetsky & Torrego 2007](http://web.mit.edu/linguistics/people/faculty/pesetsky/Pesetsky_Torrego_Agree_paper.pdf), who give important references and develop a slightly different, but influential departure from Chomsky's 2000, 2001 definition. Adger 2003 is a good book, but note that his version of agreement is non-standard (as it work up- and downwards).

#### Literature

Chomsky, Noam (2000): “Minimalist inquiries:  e framework”. In: Roger Martin & David Michaels & Juan Uriagereka, eds.: Step by Step. Essays on Minimalist Syntax in Honor of Howard Lasnik. Cambridge, MA: MIT Press, 89–156.

Chomsky, Noam (2001): “Derivation by phase”. In: Michael Kenstowicz, ed.: Ken Hale, a life in language. Cambridge, MA: MIT Press.

Adger, David (2003): Core Syntax. A Minimalist Approach. Oxford: Oxford University Press.

Pesetsky, David & Esther Torrego (2007): “Thee syntax of valuation and the interpretability of features”. In: Simin Karimi & Vida Samiian & Wendy K. Wilkins, eds.: Syntactic derivation and interpretation. In honor of Joseph E. Emonds. Amsterdam and Philadelphia: Benjamins, 262–294. doi: 10.1075/la.101.14pes.